# Extract data from application using python

Tags: python, windows

I want to know if it is possible to extract data out of any windows application.
The problem i am facing is that i want to be able to monitor the text that is being generated on a certain label field on an window application i have running on my desktop.

I want to know if there is a python library or way to read the values generated by the application.

Just to make it clear an example would be:

If i use the default calc.exe on windows and i want to run a script to get me the answer being displayed on the calc application.

Comment: I suspect the answer will depend a lot of the application. On one extreme, an application can handle all of its graphics internally and not expose anything but a bitmap that the OS shows on the screen. On the other extreme, it might use various OS services to provide hooks for things like screen-reading software which could make your goal very easy. Many applications will be somewhere in the middle. Can you say what the real application you're targeting is?

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Gray-Hat-Python-Programming-Engineers/dp/1593271921 goes through many tutorials including things very similar to whaa tyou want